# Insert tex code in pdf document as metadata

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata

I am trying to save the `LaTeX` code needed for generating some document in the document itself as metadata. So far I found the command to set the `pdf` metadata using the `hyperref` package but now I am stuck....

This clearly does not work..

```
% file.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref,listings}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor=myself,
    pdftitle=Title,
    pdfsubject={\lstinputlisting{file.tex}}
}

\begin{document}
Hello world  
\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess is that this is not possible but a workaround could be embedding the file as an attachment, using packages as `embedfile` or `attachfile`.

Comment: @Bordaigorl thanks I'll take a look. With some Java code I can do this but then I have to run an application after the compilation with `LaTeX`... not so fast...